# How to get multiple animations in an .Rmd file?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to include several animations in an RMarkdown file using the `fig.show='animate'` option. for some reason only the first one is displayed. Any ideas why?

````
---
title: "animate"
author: "Mark Heckmann"
date: "5. September 2014"
output: html_document
---

```{r animation1, echo=FALSE, fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls'}
for (i in 1:20)
  plot(1:i, col=i)
```

```{r animation2, echo=FALSE, fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls'}
for (i in 20:1)
  plot(1:i, col=i)
```
````

**UPDATE**

I am on another machine (MacOS) now and here it works. Question temporarily withdrawn ;)

Comment: What is the result of a `sessionInfo()` and the version of RStudio you are using?

Comment: I ask this because I am using Ubuntu, and I had a little of trouble with this "animation" feature. But once the problem solved (ffmpeg was missing), I have two beautiful animations in the HTML doc produced with your code.

Comment: Also, try maybe to click "Open in browser"

Comment: I just found this posting... I'm having the same issue. Using Windows with latest RStudio and R (3.2). It doesn't seem to be a browser related issue. I've tried to output file in multiple browsers. It seems the HTML code for the second animation (or any after the first) is missing.